# Continuous function in a specific point

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^6+y^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $0$ for $(x,y)=0$. Is the function continuous in point $(0,0)$?

What I have made is:

$$\frac{x^2y}{x^6+y^2}<\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}<\frac{x^2y^2}{2|xy|} < \frac{|xy|}{2}$$

and since $\frac{|xy|}{2} \to 0$, it follows that:

I can say that $lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^6+y^2} = 0$
Is this right?

Comment: $\frac{0.01\cdot1}{0.000001+1}<\frac{0.01\cdot1}{0.01+1}$ is false.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are right. But what if I say that $\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}<\frac{x^2y}{2(|x||y|)}=\frac{|x|y}{2y}$ can I claim now that the function is continuous in (0,0)?

Comment: I did not check your other inequalities but they are wrong. The function is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the curve $y=x^4$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

With $x=\sqrt[3]t$, consider

$$\frac{t^{2/3}y}{t^2+y^2}$$ and convert to polar coordinates.

Comment: Okay, I will try the way you told me. Let $t=cosz, y=sinz$ Then $\frac{cosz^(2/3).sinz}{cosz^2+sinz^2}=cosz^(2/3)sinz$ But then if I say that both x and y go to 0, then z must approach pi/2,3pi/2 for x=0 and z must approach 0,pi or 2pi for y going to 0.

Comment: Well I do not what are polar coordinates then, because that is what I know from class.

Comment: Lol, ofc you can believe whatever you want, all the freedom is yours, but dude we haven't  yet studied polar coordinates

Comment: However, now I am reading about them because of you, thx